# matplotlib and seaborn error bars with open circle

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I am using matplotlib and seaborn to make pretty plots.  I think error bars with open circles are very nice.  The solution when just using matplotlib is to use something like,

```
plt.errorbar(x,y,yerr=err,fmt='o',color='gray',linewidth=0.5,mfc='white',zorder=1)
```

However if I import seaborn it removes the outer circle which I don't want to happen.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to set the `markeredgewidth` or `mew` parameter to a positive number.